# Process terminate with SIGILL using valgrind

Tags: c++

I tried to use valgrind in order to debug some memory corruption, but when I run the program to debug using valgrind it ends reporting `Illegal instruction`.

So I tried with this very simple code :

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

And when `valgrind a.out` fails :

> ```
> ==2677== Memcheck, a memory error detector
> ==2677== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
> ==2677== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
> ==2677== Command: ./a.out
> ==2677== 
> disInstr(arm): unhandled instruction: 0xF1010200
>                  cond=15(0xF) 27:20=16(0x10) 4:4=0 3:0=0(0x0)
> ==2677== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x4843588.
> ==2677==    at 0x4843588: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so)
> ==2677== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
> ==2677== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
> ==2677== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
> ==2677==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
> ==2677==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
> ==2677== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
> ==2677==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
> ==2677==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
> ==2677== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
> ==2677== probably kill your program.
> ==2677== 
> ==2677== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
> ==2677==  Illegal opcode at address 0x4843588
> ==2677==    at 0x4843588: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so)
> Hello==2677== 
> ==2677== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==2677==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==2677==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
> ==2677== 
> ==2677== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
> ==2677== 
> ==2677== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==2677== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 19 from 6)
> Illegal instruction
> ```

Is there a way to use valgrind on raspberry pi ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a valgrind bug [Bug 322935 - disInstr(arm): unhandled instruction: 0xF1010200, valgrind: Unrecognised instruction on Raspbian](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=322935) explains that `std::cout << std::endl` raise a SIGILL.

As the status is `RESOLVED WONTFIX`, I guess either I replace `std::end` with '\n' or I search an other way to debug.

Comment: I'm sure I've hit this before.  Now here's an odd angle: On raspbian using `\n` instead works, on pidora (same valgrind version, "-3.7.0 and LibVEX"), I get the exact same error either way ("LibVEX called failure_exit()...report_and_quit (m_libcassert.c:235)") -- prefaced by "valgrind: the 'impossible' happened"...

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to work around this problem by making sure the system can't find the particular library that contains the non-standard ARM instructions.

On Raspberry Pi 2:
 `sudo mv /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so_OLD`

On Raspberry Pi 3:
 `sudo mv /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem.so_OLD`

This may produce some error messages regarding the missing libraries, but they do not seem to affect the proper functioning of Valgrind.